# VBA: Changing values in an array

Tags: arrays, vba, type-mismatch

Hello everyone I have written a line of code that goes down a column and does a vlookup. the results of that function are then placed into an array to later be changed. some of the lookup values are not in the lookup range and thus returns an error. I am trying to place this column in an array, change the values of error to 0 or an empty cell, then replace the original column with the array. here is what i have written but i keep getting a type mismatch error on line:

```
If myArray(x) = "#N/A" Then myArray(x) = Empty
```

here is the code in question.

```
Dim myArray() As Variant
Dim DataRange As Range
Dim cell As Range
Dim x As Long

  Set DataRange = ActiveSheet.UsedRange

  ReDim myArray(DataRange.Cells.Count)

  For Each cell In DataRange.Cells
    myArray(x) = cell.Value
    x = x + 1
  Next cell
  
  
  For x = LBound(myArray) To UBound(myArray)
    If myArray(x) = "#N/A" Then myArray(x) = Empty
  Next X

End Sub
```

When i print the array the errors's turn into Error 2042 i have tried replacing the if with

```
if myArray(x) = "Error 2042" then myArray(x) = Empty
```

but this still returns a type mismatch error

Comment: An error value is not a `String`. So you can't compare an actual `#N/A` error to the strings `"#N/A"` or `"Error 2042"`. See the linked thread for the correct approach.

Comment: @BigBen thank you for the help. how do i overwrite the original range with the modified array

Comment: Really there's an easier way to do this using `Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeErrors)`, no need for an intermediate array. And even if you were to use an array, it's better to use [this approach](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/ArraysAndRanges.aspx) to create it, modify it, and write it back to the sheet. No need to loop over each cell.

Comment: thanks man you are a hero. 1/3rd of my day has been spent working on this. i dont know how to give you points but i would.

Comment: one final note if this isnt deleted but SpecialCells(xlCellTypeErrors) does not exist checked the microsoft support page and everything its not a special cells method @BigBen

Comment: Sorry, brain fart, it would be using `Range.SpecialCells` with its second parameter: e.g. `.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, xlErrors)`.

Comment: For posterities sake the actual formual should be `Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, 16)` using the error formula constant. Also I believe because in my case the code that creates the vlookup 
`For Each cl In LookUpTableSheets(Last_Month & " BV Walk").Cells(V_Row, Last_Col + 2) = _
    Application.VLookup(cl, DataTable, 2, False)
    V_Row = V_Row + 1
Next cl`

this code does not place an error just actually "#N/A" but its and error and also not an error. The special cells method works at detecting "#N/A" errors not made by the above code but not ones made with it. Weird.